# What is the source of the object defined error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am unable to identify the *object-defined error* that is displayed. It occurs on the `Set myxlSheet` statement.

```
Private Sub LoadConfigFile(filename As String)

    Dim myXLApp As Object
    Dim myXLWorkbook As Object
    Dim myXLSheet As Object
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim ColumnCounter As Integer
    Dim RowCounter As Integer
    Dim StartRates As Boolean
    Dim tempPlanName As String, TempPreTax As String
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim LPosition As Integer

    On Error GoTo ProcError

    'check if the file exists
    If Dir(filename) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Cannot find Config file"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'clear out CRDRates table and set up to enter data
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * from [tblConfigRates]"      'clear out CRDRates table
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblConfigRates", dbOpenDynaset)

    'start MS Excel by checking if it is already open (GetObject). If not open it will error and go to CreateObject
    Set myXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    myXLApp.Visible = False       'user does not need flashing Excel on screen
    Set myXLWorkbook = myXLApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)

    Set myXLSheet = myXLWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: Is there a sheet in that workbook called `Sheet1`?

Comment: Yes Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. thee code was working perfectly previously then suddenly runs with this error.

Comment: Have you tried `Set myXLSheet = myXLWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`?